# Animate css switch

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Is there a way to animate this function?
so when it "expands" switches between the css it does this slowly/medium/fast.

```
    function changeCssClass(objDivID)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(objDivID).className=='normalSize')
        {
            document.getElementById(objDivID).className = 'expandedSize';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(objDivID).className = 'normalSize';
        }
    }
```

css code:

```
.normalSize { width:640px; height:360px; }

.expandedSize { width:1000px; height:480px; }
```

Comment: You'd be better off using a library like jQuery when it comes to animation.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use jQuery.

Comment: You might be able to use CSS animation, depending on your case.

Comment: i edited the original post with css code.
But how would you change this code to jquery?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/toggleClass, http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/switchClass - things like that.

Comment: jQuery is completely unnecessary, especially if the project doesn't use it for anything else. See the answer by Mircea. This functionality is baked into CSS3 and is usable in most modern browsers (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions )

Answer (score 1):

This is just something so easy to do with CSS transitions. It would be a pity to use anything else. Here goes:

```
   function changeCssClass() {
        if (document.getElementById('objDivID').className == 'normalSize') {
            document.getElementById('objDivID').className = 'expandedSize';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('objDivID').className = 'normalSize';
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('objDivID').onclick = function(){
        changeCssClass();
    }
```

and the CSS:

```
#objDivID {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U8yZ6/

It is triggered by an onclick but you can use any type of trigger.